# Exiting function on return

Tags: javascript

I have an array. I have a function that checks whether the array contains the number '2' or not.

If the number is found, I want the function to return true. If not, it should return false.

I wrote this:

```
function hasTwo(arr) {
    arr.forEach((x) => {
        if (x === 2) {
            console.log("Two!")
            return true
        }
    })
    console.log("No two :(")
    return false
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    
console.log(hasTwo(arr))
```

My expectation was that on the second forEach iteration, the if condition would be met and the function would return true.

However, this is the console output:

```
Two!
No two :(
false
```

I believe that the first return statement is returning from the conditional block, not the enclosing function. (Is that right?)

I've rewritten the function with a variable to store the return value:

```
function hasTwo(arr) {

let result = false

    arr.forEach((x) => {
        if (x === 2) {
            console.log("Two!")
            result = true
        }
    })

    return result
}
```

But I don't see the point of the function continuing if the x === 2 condition has been met. Is there a way to return a value and quit the function immediately?

Comment: you are returning value inside callback function

Comment: Why not use `.filter()`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Because filter doesn't quit the iteration either?

Comment: @Bergi you're right, which is why I didn't put it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot `return` from the outer function inside the `forEach` callback - that only returns from the callback function.

You cannot break a `forEach` loop (without an exception), and you should not try to. What you are actually looking for is the [`some` Array method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

```
function hasTwo(arr) {
    var result = arr.some(x => x === 2);
    console.log(result ? "Two!" : "No two :(");
    return result;
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    
console.log(hasTwo(arr))
```

Answer (score 5):

The `return` statement returns immediately from the function it's in, not from *all* surrounding functions.

You can't stop `.forEach()` iteration other than by throwing an exception, which would be counter-productive if you're concerned about performance. What you *can* do is use `.some()` instead:

```
var result = arr.some((x) => { return x === 2; });
```

The iteration with `.some()` will stop as soon as one of the callbacks returns `true`.

Comment: Why use ES6 arrow functions, shouldn't the OP use a ES6 tag for that?

Comment: @evolutionxbox there's no particular reason in this case; I was just trying to be consistent with the code in the question.

Comment: Well there's nothing particularly ES2015 specific about the question, really, but I can't muster a strong opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe use `.indexOf` instead of iterating yourself?

```
function hasTwo(arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(2) !== -1
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    
console.log(hasTwo(arr))
```

Comment: @Andy Well, you could be *even more* general and change the name to `contains`. I was just orienting myself at the question. :D

Answer (score 0):

You have two functions. So it returns from the first function and not the parent function. The parent function executes as it should. Instead, you can do something like:

```
function hasTwo(arr) {
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 2) {
        console.log("Two!");
        return true;
    }
    console.log("No two :(");
    return false;
}

let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6]    
console.log(hasTwo(arr));
```